# Virtual machines using wrong IP addresses

Tags: linux, tcpip, linux-kvm, qemu

I have a host computer (A), running three virtual machines: X,Y and Z.
They're under a NAT layer, in which the Host A is the gateway (192.168.0.1/16), and the VM's are respectively 192.168.0.2 (X), 0.3 (Y) and 0.4 (Z).

The host X (0.2) is serving a web page which returns the visitor IP:

- Host A accesses Host X's web page. Returned IP: 192.168.0.1 (correct)
- Host Y accesses Host X's web page. Returned IP: 192.168.XXX.XXX (Not his IP)
- Host Z accesses Host X's web page. Returned IP: 192.168.XXX.XXX (The same)

What should be causing this? ifconfig returns correct ip addresses, traceroute shows nothing else than direct connections. (X to Y and Z, and vice-versa)

The virtualization software is QEMU/KVM, the NAT layer has a DHCP pool begging in 192.168.128.0, which so far seems to be where the "random IP's" are located.Examples are: "192.168.151.104" and "192.168.99.240"

Neither VM is running dhcp, and all of them are clones.

Comment: How do you know that the wrong IP addresses are being returned? Have you tried ifconfig on Hosts Y and Z, to see whether their returned IP addresses exist?

Comment: As i said i used ifconfig, i don't even have dhcp running. To verify it's IP I am using PHP's "REMOTE_ADDR" variable.

Comment: If you are not running dhcpd or dhcp server anywhere you must go into each VM and set the IP addresses statically.

Comment: Thats exactly what i had done before asking... somehow after a full stop of the hyper-visor it worked, probably was some sort of bug.

Comment: How do i close this question?